# Looking for patterns to work with Timezones and dates Front-end(React) and Backend(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I am looking for development patterns to handle different timezones for the different users of a wide country or just different countries.

I wonder if there are any quite accepted and implemented in the existing world class software.

Up to now my idea is to store the user profile with the specific timezone and alter all the dates in the backend query.

The backend is going to receive the dates in local time, including the TZ, and the backend is going to store it in UTC in the db.

For retrieving a list of results this works perfectly, but for grouping queries where you need to group for example all the sales made in October, you should also group dates of the 30th of September if you are in a minus TZ or sales of the 1st of November if you are in a plus timezone.

For this scenario is to use directly the stored TZ of the user and subtract/add it to the datetime retrieved from the db with some db functions in the select clause.

Can I Explain myself?

Remember for example if I have to retrieve a couple of sales for example for the db, for getting from the 1st of September

Comment: Is your backend receiving date-only values (such as `2020-11-16`), or date-time values (such as `2020-11-16 12:34:56`)?  Also, have you read through [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and understood that the user time zone needs to be a time zone identifier (such as `America/New_York`) and not a time zone offset (such as `-05:00`)?  Which database platform are you running, and what data type is the field you storing the data in?

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson-Pint for your response, my problem is not for filtering, I am doing the things right providing to the backend the timestamp with the correspondent timezone. My  problem it is only when I have to group by months, doing the period filter fine, but showing sales of august for example (UTC) should be grouped in September. Thanks for the wiki link

Comment: I still need you to answer my questions if you'd like an actual answer.

Comment: I am using Mysql and field datatype datetime, because I've read timestamp has serious performance issues. And yes I Understood the zone identifier thing

Comment: You missed the first question.  Are you dealing with *dates* or *date+times* ?  In other words, is it the date of the order as in *"this order was placed on November 16th 2020"*, or is it the exact local time+date+timezone of the order as in *"this order was placed at 12:34:56 on November 16th 2020 in `America/Los_Angeles`"*, or do you receive a date+time+offset like `2020-11-16T12:34:56-08:00`?  This matters.

Comment: Sorry for the confussion, I am receiving in this format 2020-11-16T12:34:56-08:00

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap what you've told us:

- You receive data like `2020-11-16T12:34:56-08:00`
- You store it in terms of UTC (`2020-11-16T20:34:56Z`) into a `datetime` field in MySQL.
- You also have the user's time zone, as an IANA time zone identifier (`America/Los_Angeles`)
- You now want to write a query to get all data over a time period, such as all data within a given month.

In MySQL, the `datetime` type differs from the `timestamp` type in how it handles time zone conversions.  From [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

As such, if you were to use a `timestamp` type, the only thing you'd have to do is set your session time zone to the user's time zone when running your query.  (Read about per-session time zones [in the docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html).)

You mentioned that you chose datetime over timestamp due to a performance concern.  That is not a universal truth.  I would take a very close look at your actual usage to see if you are having a performance problem.  Its more likely that you're missing an index or writing a non-sargable query.  To my knowledge, there are not widespread performance issues with the `timestamp` type.

If you still want to use the `datetime` type, then MySQL won't do time zone conversions for you.  So, you will need to first convert the start/end datetimes from their local time to UTC.  Then you can perform a range query over those UTC values.

With *either* approach, you'll want to think about which time zone is actually relevant for the query.  In many cases it will be a business-specific time zone that matters.  In other cases it will be the users.  The use case you gave about "all sales in October" illustrates this well.  That may indeed be different for the business than for the customer if they are in different time zones.  You may want them to be different, or you  may want to force the customer to see things from the business's perspective or vice-versa.  It really just depends on how you are operating that business.

Lastly - such a query should always be performed as a *range query*, that is from start to end.  Usually that's best expressed in your `where` clause as a half-open interval, such as:

```sql
select * from Orders where OrderDate >= @start and < @end
```

If however, you are *aggregating* results and need to use a `group by` clause, then you'll need some additional steps:

- If there is a single time zone for the business, you might want to add a second field with the data pre-converted to that time zone.  It would be `date` or `datetime` - not `timestamp`.  You can then use that field for the grouping.
- You might need to run a subquery as a range query as described previously, but then converting to a specific time zone before grouping.  You can use the MySQL `convert_tz` function for that.